# Issues downloading picture to local system using OneNote API

Tags: javascript, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-msal, onenote-api, microsoft-graph-onenote

I'm trying to write a program that dowloads OneNote pages to my pc, including files in the pages. I'm stuck on the downloading images from the pages. I make a GET request and get the binary data for the image just fine, when I save it and try to open it, I get a "it looks like we don't support this file format.
The code I'm using is

```
var u16 =  btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(resp)));
var imgAsBlob = new Blob([u16], {type: 'application/octet-stream'});
var downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
downloadLink.download = "hello.png";
downloadLink.href = window.webkitURL.createObjectURL(imgAsBlob);
downloadLink.click();
```

`resp` is the responseText from the GET request with the binary data.

I've tried not using `btoa` and saving the resp directly on the blob. I've tried changing the blob type to `image/png` and I've tried escaping it using `Uint16Array(resp.length)` and equaling each byte to a byte from resp. I'm out of ideas and don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: It could be an option setting the href directly instead of making an ajax call `downloadLink.href = 'http://domain/imagepath.jpeg'`.

Comment: My problem is that, like this, I can't add the header for the authorization code. I tried adding as a param, but it requires a space that is eliminated in HTML and non-breakable space doesnt work

Comment: Ah okay, yes then you need ajax, but `var u16 =  btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(resp)));
var imgAsBlob = new Blob([u16], {type: 'application/octet-stream'});` is a little complicated and i guess there is the problem. You could take a look at how to use fetch. something like `fetch('http://domain/imagepath.jpeg').then(r => r.blob()).then(imgAsBlob => downloadLink.href = window.createObjectURL(imgAsBlob) )` (you would need to lookup how to use your auth headers there.)

Comment: It works now! Thank you so much for the help!